# NextJS 13 не прогружаются стили not-found.tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nextjs

Всем добрый день. У меня проблема. Делаю страницу 404 на NextJS, однако столкнулся с проблемой, что не грузятся стили. Я использую SCSS-модули и в других страницах всё работает.

TSX

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import styles from './not-found.module.scss';
import {FC} from "react";
import OwlButton from "@/components/OwlButton";

const NotFound: FC = () => {

    return (
        <section className={styles['NotFound']}>
            <h2 className={styles['error-code']}>404</h2>
            <p>Великая пустота затмила твой путь, ты ошибся дверью, подаван</p>
            <Link href={'/'}>
                <OwlButton message={'На главную'} type={'FILLED'}/>
            </Link>
        </section>
    );
};

export default NotFound;
```

SCSS

```
@import "./adaptiv-font";

.NotFound {
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 70px;

  h2.error-code {
    @include adaptiv-font(268, 90);
  }
}
```

[image: Пример отстутсвия применения стилей]